# [ERROR] ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, createquery

There are two entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Man extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Trying to execute the following method:

```
@Test
public void clear(EntityManager em) {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    System.out.println(em
            .createQuery("delete from Man m where m.id > 14582647")
            .executeUpdate());
    tx.commit();
}
```

Get the error:

```
[ERROR] ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

hibernate.show_sql shows sql-queries:

```
Hibernate: insert into HT_Man select man0_.id as id from Man man0_ inner join Person man0_1_ on man0_.id=man0_1_.id where id=14582647
Hibernate: delete from HT_Man
```

The error occurs in a place **where id = 14582647** as there must be more than just **id**, and for example **man0_.id**. How to generate the correct sql-query?

Answer (score 1):

Add a @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation on Man class:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "<pk column name in Man table>")
public class Man extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Also, you should define a Discriminator column in Person and the @DiscriminatorValue in Man so that Hibernate can figure out which tables to join (when you introduce say a Woman table).